# JS addClass and fadeIn/fadeOut together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

is it possible to combine together addClass and fadeIn with JS?

I'm not really practice with JS but I'm trying to develop a script where on text hover, the div container change background fading in/out.

I made a CodePen to show better what I'm trying to achieve. When you hover a title, the background appear but without any sort of transition.

https://codepen.io/Freddan3/pen/NWzpKRz

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#1st').hover(function () {
        $('#BG').addClass('first');
        $('#BG').removeClass('second');
    });
    $('#2nd').hover(function () {
        $('#BG').addClass('second');
        $('#BG').removeClass('first');
    });
});
```

```css
section{
  min-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.title{
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.first {
    background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/11/03/15/24/coffee-7567749_960_720.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.second {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/10/25/13/28/hanoi-7545860_960_720.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="BG">
  <div id="1st" class="title">TITLE</div>
  <div id="2nd" class="title">TITLE 2</div>
</section>
```

Is it possible to add the fadeIn to the current item you are hovering and fadeOut the other one?

Thanks in advance for any kind of suggestions :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a second `div` arround your `#BG` and give both different `background-image`s:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="BG">
    <h2 id="1st">First</h2>
    <h2 id="2nd">Second</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/11/03/15/24/coffee-7567749_960_720.jpg);
}

#BG {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/10/25/13/28/hanoi-7545860_960_720.jpg);
}
```

Then you would animate the `opacity` of `#BG` on hover:

```js
$('#1st').hover(function () {
    $('#BG').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
});
$('#2nd').hover(function () {
    $('#BG').animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
});
```

To prevent the content (`#1st` and `#2nd`) to fade away too, you could wrap it in an extra `div` with position absolute:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="BG"></div>
  
  <div id="content">
    <h2 id="1st">First</h2>
    <h2 id="2nd">Second</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
$('#1st').hover(function () {
    $('#BG').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
});
$('#2nd').hover(function () {
    $('#BG').animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
});
```

```css
#container {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/11/03/15/24/coffee-7567749_960_720.jpg);
}

#BG {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/10/25/13/28/hanoi-7545860_960_720.jpg);
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="BG"></div>
  
  <div id="content">
    <h2 id="1st">First</h2>
    <h2 id="2nd">Second</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @biberman, you are great!

Your solution is making everything working properly. I just have a last question:

I would like to use more items (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc..), is it possible to make the div #BG changing background image depending on which item I'm hovering? Otherwise, to continue your script I should add another extra div with another id: div id=BG2, isn't it?

Comment: That's right. The more backgrounds you want, the more emty BG divs you could use and toggle them with any event handler and condition that you like...